# Velocity of a swimmer relative to the Earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, relative-motion

> Julia can swim 0.34 m/s in still water. She swims directly east across a river that is 180 m wide and lands at a point that is 81 m north downstream. Determine Julia's velocity while swimming relative to the Earth.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. How can I find the swimmer's velocity relative to the Earth if I don't have the velocity of the river relative to the Earth?

Any hints or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you draw a triangle where the sides represent her velocity relative to the river, her velocity relative to the Earth, and the velocity of the river relative to the Earth, that triangle should be similar to a triangle whose sides represent the distance she traveled relative to the river, the distance she traveled relative to the Earth, and the distance the water traveled relative to the Earth.